# Earliest Sources for Custom of Not Shaving from 17th of Tammuz

Tags: minhag, provenance, three-weeks, shaving, haircuts

What are the earliest sources for the custom of not shaving from the 17th of Tammuz?

The Shulchan Aruch (OC 551:3) only mentions this only in the week of the 9th of Av.

> שָׁבוּעַ שֶׁחָל בּוֹ תִּשְׁעָה בְּאָב, אֲסוּרִים לְסַפֵּר וּלְכַבֵּס, אֲפִלּוּ אֵינוֹ רוֹצֶה לְלָבְשׁוֹ עַתָּה אֶלָּא לְהַנִּיחוֹ לְאַחַר ט' בְּאָב, וַאֲפִלּוּ אֵין לוֹ אֶלָּא חָלוּק אֶחָד, אָסוּר

The Rama there records only the practice beginning in Av.

> **הגה**: וְאָנוּ נוֹהֲגִין לְהַחְמִיר בְּכָל זֶה מִתְּחִלַּת רֹאשׁ חֹדֶשׁ עַד אַחַר הַתַּעֲנִית

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (122), however, records the custom beginning with the 17th of Tammuz

> כֵּיוָן שֶׁבְּשִׁבְעָה עָשָׂר בְּתַמּוּז הִתְחִילוּ צָרוֹת הַחֻרְבָּן, לָכֵן נוֹהֲגִין קְצָת אֲבֵלוּת מִיּוֹם זֶה עַד אַחַר תִּשְׁעָה בְּאָב...וְכֵן נוֹהֲגִין שֶׁאֵין מִסְתַּפְּרִין בְּיָמִים אֵלּוּ

The Aruch Hashulchan (551:16) records the custom beginning at the 17th of Tammuz as well.

> ודע, דאף על גב דכיבוס אין אנו מחמירין רק מראש חודש, אבל תספורת אנו נוהגין לאסור משבעה עשר בתמוז, משום דתספורת אינו שכיח ככיבוס. ולכן בתשעה ימים לא יהא ניכר איסורו, ולכן מאריכין אותו מן שבעה עשר בתמוז.

Comment: mevaqesh, your edit invalidates existing answers. It should be rolled back and you should ask a new question.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1229/policy-regarding-changing-questions-after-a-period-of-time

Comment: @Yishai At the minimum I had to remove the mistaken presentation of the Rama.

Comment: You can add in the correction, just don't change the question to look for a source prior to the Ramo.

Comment: @mevaqesh You can only edit such that it doesn't invalidate existing upvoted answers, per http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1231/759. It's ok to have a mistake in a question that is corrected by an answer. That's what Q&A and learning is all about.

Answer (score 6):

The Rama himself actually forbids haircuts starting on the 17th of Tammuz ([ShA OC 551:4](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayyim.551.4)). In his Darkei Moshe, he cites [Minhagim Tirna on Tammuz](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33774&st=&pgnum=55) (written ~1400 CE) which mentions this custom.

Comment: Indeed. How embarrassing.